# grep for numbers over 10

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

I'm looking through a file for specific kernels.

I want everything from 3.8. to 3.17.

egrep 3.[8-17] is kind of the thing I want but that obviously doesn't work.

How do I grep using the example above?

Thanks

Comment: See http://superuser.com/a/439694/513541

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $'3.8\n3.17' | grep -E '3\.([89]|1[0-7])'
3.8
3.17
```

But it is probably necessary to limit the search string because that would match `3.81`, too. The question is: What is the next character or do the strings end there?

Comment: Just add `'([^0-9].*)?'`

Comment: well... That and the -x switch or a trailing $, that is. I thought you were using -x before, I guess.